# Getting 404 error on production server during page reload or refresh in Reactjs app.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I am new in Reactjs, and I am working on Reactjs v15.4.2. When i build the code for production using "npm run build" cmd and uploaded to server. Everything thing working fine but once I reload or refresh the page then getting 404 file not found error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this code to root directory. This is working fine for me

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by adding a .htaccess file to root of the app with the following code :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png)
 RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have implemented your solution but it is not working for me, if you have another solution please suggest me.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Excellent, can you mark the answer as correct. Cheers

Comment: Anyone else coming here and seeing this, I did the same but am using NGINX so had to use this site to translate and it worked. Just copy and paste the above into it and then into your NGINX config where appropriate. https://winginx.com/en/htaccess